# If $N$ is neighborhood of $x_0 \in M$ in $(M,d)$, then it is also neighborhood of $x_0 \in M$ in $(M,d')$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am trying to prove that the limit of a sequence is indifferent to the distance function used. (Meaning the values are equal to another). This is definitely true if "neighbourhood" is indifferent from the definition of distance.

Geometrically speaking, the proof seems quite intuitive. For every norm the property $d(ax, ay) = a \times d(x,y)$ shows why this must be true. But I am lacking the proof giving only the property of a distance function.

The problem is that I cannot find any definition of continuity that is not using a distance function. If I could show that every metric is continuous, then I could use that $d(x,y) > 0$ and $d(x,x) = 0$ and then I could convert between both.

Any Ideas?
Thank you.

Edit: I am also wondering if you could maybe use some algebra, defining a function $f: d,d' \mapsto g $, where $g(d) = d'$ and then show some properties about $f$...

Comment: It is definitely not true that every neighborhood of a point with respect to a metric is a neighborhood of a point with respect to every other metric. This would imply that all topologies induced by a metric are the same. Do you have a specific space $M$ in mind that might satisfy additional properties?

Comment: But how can the limit of a sequence be indifferent to the metric used? One would argue that the limit of $1 ,\frac{3}{2} , \frac{7}{4}, ...$ is $2$ with respect to every metric.

Comment: In the trivial metric ($d(x,y) = 1$ for all $x\ne y$), the sequence $1, 3/2, 7/4, \dotsc $ does not converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that if $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \to y$ in a metric space, then $x=y$, which follows from the fact that all metric spaces are Hausdorff. The proof is that if $x \neq y$ then $d(x,y) > 0$, so there are disjoint balls around $x, y$. For $n$ large, the sequence cannot be in both balls since they are disjoint, so we have a contradiction.

It is also easy to construct different metrics $d, d'$ for which $x_n \to x$ wrt to $d$, but $x_n$ does not converge wrt to $d'$.
For example, in the discrete metric $d'$, $x_n \to x$ if and only if $x_n = x$ for all $n$ large, i.e. if and only if the sequence is eventually constant equal to $x$. So any sequence converging to $x$ in the usual way that is not eventually constant won't converge wrt $d'$.
For another example, take the usual metric $d$, but take $d'(x,y)$ to be $\min(|x-y|,1)$ if $x,y$ are either both rational or both irrational, and $d'(x,y) = 1$ otherwise. You can check that $d'$ is a metric. Now take rationals $x_n \to \sqrt{2}$ in the usual metric. By defintion $d(x_n, \sqrt{2}) = 1$ for all $n$ since $x_n$ is rational and $\sqrt{2}$ is not, so $x_n$ does not converge to $\sqrt{2}$ wrt $d'$. In this case $x_n$ does not converge at all with respect to $d'$.

What is more difficult is to find an example for which $x_n \to x$ wrt $d$ but $x_n \to y$ wrt $d'$ with $x \neq y$. A discussion of this topic can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53971/example-of-sequences-with-different-limits-for-two-norms. You can find my own example there as well.

What is true is that any two metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by a norm (i.e. $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$ for a norm $||\cdot||$) are equivalent, i.e. they generate the same topology and thus have the same convergent sequences with the same limits.

Comment: In my mind this is crazy, but yet amazing.

Comment: As you progress in mathematics you will find crazier and crazier things, and you will learn to recognize what hypotheses your intuition is actually using (in this case, you were clearly thinking of norms, where the theorem is in fact true for finite dimensional spaces). Once you can recognize that your intuition is based in certain hypotheses, it becomes less and less surprising when leaving off a hypothesis yields a counterexample. But don't worry, it never ceases to be *interesting*.